# Understanding how stack frames work in recursive function

Tags: python, function, recursion, stack, frame

Python/CS newbie here, trying to understand how a particular recursive function works "under the hood" in terms of how the function's stack frames are operating and what values they're "holding."

I know a lot has been written/posted about recursive functions on here, and there are illustrative examples of how they work, but the concepts of recursion and how stacks work/what they do in a recursive function are a little tricky and I'm not finding any clear and concise explanations.

Let's say we have the following recursive function that reverses the characters in a string:

```
text = "hello"
def reverse_string(text):
        if len(text) <= 1:
            return text
        return reverse_string(text[1:]) + text[0]
```

which outputs: `olleh`

I'm thinking that the frames for the `reverse_string(text[1:])` work as follows:

```
Global frame
text    "hello"
reverse_string  

reverse_string
text    "hello"

reverse_string
text    "ello"

reverse_string
text    "llo"

reverse_string
text    "lo"

reverse_string
text    "o"

Return
value   "o"
```

But what happens after the value `"o"` is returned and the terminating base condition is met? How does `text[0]` work in the function to finally arrive at `"olleh"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just taking your example for a walk.

Once we reach the terminating condition, the remaining frames are pop'd in reverse order.

Suppose we reach the terminating condition in which case `return text` is "hit" and `text = "o"` is returned. Then in the previous frame we have `reverse_string(text[1:]) + text[0]` but this is just `reverse_string("o") + "l" = "o" + "l" = "ol" = reverse_string(text[1:])`, where `reverse_string(text[1:])` is the call from the previous frame (the one for which `text` was equal to "llo"). Continuing this logic, `reverse_string("lo") + "l" = "ol" + "l" = "oll"`.

We continue this same idea until we reach the "top" frame where we finally return "olleh".

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is probably a stupid question, but can you explain why it is that the frames are pop'd in reverse order? How/why does that happen? When looking at the code in http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html it looks like after "o" is finally return (and the base condition is met) it goes "back up" through the frames, but I don't understand why.

Comment: The reason it goes back up the frames is due to the `return` statement. A returned function "returns" to where it was called with whatever result it has (unless it's void). In the case of `reverse_string(str)`, you are returning the reversed string in the very last "pop": reverse_string("ello") + "h". And remember, reverse_string("ello") is returning the value "olle".

Comment: So the function doesn't actually end when the base condition is met, right? It seems as though in the conditional base condition statement, only `text` is being returned, not the `reverse_string` function. Why when return text is "hit" and `text = "o"` the function then moves down to the `return reverse_string(text[1:]) + text[0]` ?

Comment: To your last point, this happens because it's actually returning from the frame where `return text` was "hit" and going to the line where `reverse_string("o")` was called: `return reverse_string("o") + text[0]`

Comment: Thanks. I think the missing piece here was elucidating the concepts of Winding and Unwinding with recursive functions.